# undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hi there I am getting a  NoMethodError in Users#show error in my Rails 3.2 app using devise.

Error on line 2 of my show below:

```
 <strong>Firstname:</strong>
   <%= @user.firstname %>
 </p>
 <p>
 <strong>dateofbirth:</strong>
```

(If I remove the first name box it does the error for dateofbirth, etc.)

I'm using devise for my users, but generated a user controller in which to place my views.

I'm not sure what the problem is because I ran my migration and firstname exists in the schema

Here's the user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
#  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def find
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :firstname, :dateofbirth, :lastname, :gender, :location, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

Comment: try getting rid of the `def user_params` at the bottom - if you're not using Rails 4, I think this won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller has two show methods defined.  Try removing the second one.  I believe the empty show method is overwriting your filled-in show method.  In your view, @user doesn't exist so it evaluates to nil.  Nil has neither a firstname method, nor dateofbirth method.  Hence the NoMethodError.